# How do i change the source code of randomForest in Mahout?

Tags: hadoop, mahout

present implementation of randomForest in mahout not dealing with missing values in big data, it just simply skip all the rows which are containing missing values.

if i want to make use of this source code to identify misssing values in big data, what are the modifications i have to make in source code?

thanks,
rajkumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take care of this at mapreduce level by setting non-skipping of bad records..it will fail the job in cases of missing values